# Java Combinarion of Values in a Map

Tags: java, hashmap

I've got a Map of this type: `Map<String, List<String>>`

Map contains this data:

```
{
  A[a1, a2, a3]
  B[b1 ,b2]
  C[c1, c2]
}
```

I want to obtain this:

```
a1,b1,c1
a1,b1,c2
a1,b2,c1
a2,b1,c1
a2,b1,c2
a2,b2,c1
a3,b1,c1
a3,b1,c2
a3,b2,c1
```

What is the best way to do with Java 8? Consider that each key may contains a lot of values.

This is the code that I have written:

```java
Map<String, List<String>> mapPnMatricesImpact = stream(matrixValue.split("@"))
    .map(s -> s.split("\\|"))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a[0],
        Collectors.mapping(a -> a[1], Collectors.toList())));

mapPnMatricesImpact
    .forEach((key, value) -> {
        List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
        keys.add(key);
        Stream<List<String>> product = value.stream().flatMap(a ->
            keys.stream().flatMap(b -> Stream.of(Arrays.asList(a, b)))
        );
        product.forEach(p -> { logger.warn("zzz --> " + p); });
    });
```

Comment: Why `a1,b2,c2` or `a2,b2,c2` .. are not in list ? For combination recursion is a good approach.

Comment: Then it's not called combination at all, explain what is the logic behind your output.

Comment: At the beginning of prcess a have a STRING as this: A|a1@A|a2@A|a3@B|b1@B|b2@C|c1@C|c2 and I must have a combination of all values as indicated above. I think that the first step is obtain a Map with keys (Caps Loc) an related values

Comment: a1,b2,c2 and a2,b2,c2 and a3,b2,c2 must belong to list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the recursive way. For every key of map you can select an element and add list and keep doing for element of key. Then collect in list.

```
  List<List<String>> getAllCom(int index, List<List<String>> list, List<String> curr){
    if(index >= list.size()) return Arrays.asList(curr);
    List<List<String>> res = new ArrayList<>(); 
    for (String e : list.get(index)) {
      List<String> now = new ArrayList<>(curr);
       now.add(e);
       res.addAll(getAllCom(index + 1, list, now));
    }
    return res;
  }
```

Demo:

```
Map<String, List<String>> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("A", Arrays.asList("a1","a2","a3"));
data.put("B", Arrays.asList("b1","b2"));
data.put("C", Arrays.asList("c1","c2"));

List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>(data.values());
System.out.println(getAllCom(0, list, Collections.emptyList()));
```

Output:

```
[[a1, b1, c1], [a1, b1, c2], [a1, b2, c1], [a1, b2, c2], [a2, b1, c1], [a2, b1, c2], [a2, b2, c1], [a2, b2, c2], [a3, b1, c1], [a3, b1, c2], [a3, b2, c1], [a3, b2, c2]]
```